# Need help to start with any good framework for MVC3 to build web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I need to build a custom web application on asp.net mvc3 platform.

I need following major modules in it:

1. User management with Authentication & Roles
2. Activity Logging & Error Logging
3. CMS to manage page contents
4. Modular - Plug-able architecture
5. Module for managing Email notifications, etc.
6. Ability add new module by way of adding new plugin

I'm basically looking for a framework kind of a thing for MVC3 based on which i can build my application. I'm fine with it even if it doesn't have a CMS built into it.

Can you guys help me find the one best suited for this kind of a purpose.

Comment: Maybe Orchard? http://orchard.codeplex.com/

Comment: That's a non-constructive question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following

1. http://www.mvccms.com/
2. http://cmsmvc.codeplex.com/
3. http://atomiccms.codeplex.com/
4. http://mytripmvc.codeplex.com/